# How to change ordering admin.UserAdmin in Django Microsoft Auth

Tags: office365api, django-microsoft-authentication

I'm encountering an issue with the quick installation of a certain package. I've followed all the instructions outlined in the documentation here, but I'm facing an error when i try to run migration(step 7 from instruction https://django-microsoft-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html).

The error message I'm getting is as follows:

<class 'microsoft_auth.admin.UserAdmin'>: (admin.E033) The value of 'ordering[0]' refers to 'username', which is not a field of 'users.User'.

My User model uses email instead of a username, and I have a UserAdmin class defined in admin.py. I created a CustomUser class inheriting from the default User, where I changed the ordering to use email. I registered CustomUser and unregistered UserAdmin, but the error persists. Has anyone encountered a similar issue before?

I appreciate any help or insights into resolving this problem.

I created a CustomUser class inheriting from the default User, where I changed the ordering to use email. I registered CustomUser and unregistered UserAdmin, i expected that error will be gone

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title is just the useless (and improper) repetition of the tag information. The title should be clear and descriptive enough that a future site user skimming a list of search results will know what it contains. For suggestions on writing a good title, see [ask].